# How can I apply symmetry operations to wavefunctions obtained via VASP to map them to the whole BZ from the irreducible wedge?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp

I have developed a Python tool that extracts the plane wave coefficients and Gvectors from a `WAVECAR` file and I'm able to get the real space wavefunction for that particular Bloch state with a Fourier transform.

I want to be able to get the wavefunction and/or plane wave coefficients for a symmetrically related kpoint in the 1st BZ. The `WAVECAR` only contains Bloch states from an irreducible region if the ISYMM parameter is > 0, hence wanting to re-expand this set to the whole BZ.

The documentation for another DFT software, ABINIT outlines the following relationships:
$$\epsilon_{\mathbf{Rk}} = \epsilon_{\mathbf{k}}\tag{1}$$
$$u_{\mathbf{Rk}}(\mathbf{r}) = u_{\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{R^{-1}r})\tag{2}$$

where $\epsilon$ is the energy eignenvalue, $u_{\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r})$ is the Bloch-periodic part of the wavefunction at Bloch state ($n$), $\mathbf{k}$ and $\mathbf{R}$ is some operation matrix. I have tried implenting this relationship where I get a set of $R$ operators from the space group of the BZ. The implementation fails on the first test, where $\mathbf{R}$ corresponds to the time-inversion operator (i.e. $\mathbf{R}=-\mathbf{I}$).

At first I thought it was my code (it possible still is!), but after looking at the above relationships, if we substitute $\mathbf{R}=-\mathbf{I}$ into $u_{\mathbf{Rk}}(\mathbf{r}) = u_{\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{R^{-1}r})$, we get:
$$u_{\mathbf{-k}}(\mathbf{r}) = u_{\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{-r})\tag{3}$$

(since $(-\mathbf{I})^{-1}=-\mathbf{I}$)

I was under the understanding that for time inversion symmetry,
$$u_{\mathbf{-k}}(\mathbf{r}) = u^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r})\tag{4}$$
which would only hold in this case if $u_{\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r})$ has even symmetry in $\mathbf{r}$ for the real part and odd for the imaginary.

I'm not convinced this is the case for all wavefunctions.
Furthermore, if we apply this operation to the zone centred wavefunction ($\mathbf{k=0}$), we get:
$$u_{\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r}) = u_{\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{-r})\tag{5}$$
(since $-\mathbf{k}=\mathbf{k}$ for $\mathbf{k=0}$)
Wouldn't this imply that such a wavefunction must have even symmetry, or should time inversion not apply to  $\mathbf{k=0}$?

My question is quite general and applies if the above is true:

How do you apply the BZ symmetry operations to wavefunction data in an irreducible region to reconstruct the full k-point mesh?

Comment: +10. I'm surprised no one commented on this yet! Anyway, welcome to our new community and thank you for contributing your question here (better to welcome you late than never!) In the last 6+ months have you figured out anything about this? Is it still a problem for you? Please update us! I've added equation numbers: These are useful even if you're not referring to the equations in your post, because now others can refer to them as "Eq 4" instead of "the equation after the words "time inversion symmetry" (for example).

Comment: Eq 2 is missing the phase factor exp(-iRt), where t is the translation. See, for example, eq 6 in the ABINIT documentation https://docs.abinit.org/theory/wavefunctions/ . Time-reversal symmetry is explicitly covered on that page, as well.

Comment: The transformations you have outlined seem to be correct, except for the missing phase factor Phil Hasnip pointed out, and your approach looks like the one I implemented in CASTEP.  As for Eq. 5, congratulations: you just proved that the KS orbitals must be real at k=0 to satisfy both the identity and time-reversal symmetries. For bonus points, try and prove they must also be real for k on the Zone-Boundary.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I did end up resolving this. I believe the reason I wasn't seeing real wavefunctions at k=0 was because I was performing DFT with hybrid functionals in VASP, thus the orbitals weren't true KS orbitals. 

Thanks also for adding the equation number references and pointing out the phase factor (I was aware of this but neglected it since I was only considering proper and improper rotations without translation i.e. no screw symmetries etc.) but I should have included this for completeness.